# Python.Net C# using thread to call python function

Tags: python, c#, multithreading, python.net

I am currently working with C# and Python through PythonNet. It works well calling and using python functions from C#. However, the problem is when I tried to call python function in async condition by using multi-thread. As I googled so far, I found some issues that python has "GIL" so that it blocks multi-threading. Even that case, I can still call python function in async and use it if it was written in Built-in functions only in python, which means, it is not possible to use other library functions in python.

My questions,

1. is there any other way to use mulit-threading in pythonNet
2. why I can't import libraries in python when I tried in async

Answer (score 0):

According to pyhtonnet documentation

- If you plan to use Python objects from multiple threads, also call

```
PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()
```

Source : https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet